# Vertically aligning anchor tags to middle. What am I missing?

Tags: html, css

I know this is a simple question, as has been asked before, but for some unknown reason the correct solution is not working for me.

I have an ecommerce site that displays product images of varying height on a category page. All of these elements are contained within a table row, each in their own table cell and anchor tag.

I need the images to center vertically within the cell, but they will not obey. I created a js fiddle to confirm my css was correct:
http://jsfiddle.net/hzg7j7nc/

In that fiddle the images are aligning vertically using `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:middle;`. However, this same setup on my live site is not vertically aligning the images.

I'm sure it's some simple css error that I have tried to track down for over 2 hours now, and have failed. Maybe a fresh set of eyes could catch it?

You can view this in action at:
http://xzkpt.jmsko.servertrust.com/Guitars-s/1820.htm

I've attached a screen shot of the vertical alignment not working on my site:
[image]

Comment: add `vertical-align: middle;` for the parent `td`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your category.css (line 5) change this:

```
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:nth-child(5n+1) > td[width="33%"] {
  border-top: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
}
```

to this:

```
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:nth-child(5n+1) > td[width="33%"] {
  border-top: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
  vertical-align: middle; /*new */
}
```

That will fix your issue.

Comment: Geesh, I can't believe I spent two hours looking for that... Thanks for saving my sanity dippas.

Comment: Yea, I have to wait 8 min.